# How "much" should belief be weighted against numerical measures of accuracy/correctness?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, interpretation

How "much" should belief be weighted against numerical measures of accuracy/correctness?

It's possible to devise numerically low-quality models, but that have very good empirical validity, based on understanding the phenomenon that's being modeled.

OTOH, it's also possible to devise numerically high-quality models that are e.g. underfitted or overfitted and therefore do not produce a quality insight to the empirical phenomenon.

So how "much" should one weight intuition gained from e.g. past literature and personal experience/analysis versus numerical measures of accuracy?

Comment: What do you mean by belief? Is it a quality measured by humans?

Comment: @NicolasMartin It's related to beliefs to e.g. select a test set that's not representative of the population vs selecting one that is. Or knowing, what's a representative set. Both of the earlier approaches are in theory appropriate, but not in terms of soundness. Similarly, having an idea about what things should look (the Bayesian prior) should be included, if such idea exists.